# Javascript if/else statement using image src as condition

Tags: javascript

I have a voting script with an arrow system (upvotes and downvotes).If user clicks upvote, the arrow changes to the green arrow, meaning vote registered. If they click again, I want the arrow to revert back to the original image. However, using my code, it changes the image on the first like, but doesn't revert back on a second click.

```
if (like.src = 'vote_triangle.png') {
  like.src = 'vote_triangle_like.png';
} else {
  like.src = 'vote_triangle.png';
}
```

Comment: Well, first of all, you want `like.src == 'vote_triangle.png'`. Note the `==`. Otherwise, you're assigning `like.src` in the `if`.

Comment: Worth noting that the above comment is the correct answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a more lenient if statement like:

```
if (like.src.indexOf('vote_triangle.png')!=-1) {
  like.src = 'vote_triangle_like.png';
} else {
  like.src = 'vote_triangle.png';
}
```

Comment: Hey @techfoobar, do you have an idea why if(element.src == "img_path") {} would not work?

Comment: If `img_path` is specified fully (i.e. exactly as it is in `element.src`, the full case-sensitive path to the url of the image), it will definitely work.

Answer (score 2):

I know it's a very old thread, but I would like to add my findings here for future reference.

I found the following code wasn't working:

```
function swapImage() {
    var element = document.getElementById("myImage");        

    if (element.src == "image1.png") {
        element.src = "image2.png";
    } else {
        element.src = "image1.png"
    }
}
```

Showing alerts containing the `element.src` taught me it contained the full path to the image in my local machine. Thus, the if statement had been always evaluated to false.

To fix that in a logical manner, what I did was get the attribute of the element, as the following code shows.

```
function swapImage() {
    var element = document.getElementById("myImage");

    if (element.getAttribute("src") == "image1.png") {
        element.src = "image2.png";
    } else {
        element.src = "image1.png";
    }
}
```

By using the function `getAttribute("attributeName")`, I was able to retrieve the path contained in the src relatively to the project directory.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest, instead of using img soruce as conditional statement, use a global variable, change its state once the upvote is clicked by say +1 and for downvotes -1.

```
//when 0, show upvote image, make it a global by declaring before any function
var UpVote = 0;

//when upvote clicked, when greater than 0, show down vote img
UpVote = UpVote +1 ;

//conditional logic for img source
if(UpVote > 0){
  like.src = 'vote_triangle.png';
}
else{
  like.src = 'vote_triangle_like.png';
}
```